Combine filter with character limit in autocomplete result
Drupal version: 10.2.4
using contrib module "Views Autocomplete Filter" version: 2.0.2
I have a content type: Articles
Fields it contain: Title, Body & Image
I have created views for listing all article with title and body filed value(Body value trimmed to 100char limit) with three dots added at the end.
So, in the listing page, body field will be displayed only 100chars, and once user clicks on title, they will be taken to article detail page.
Also, added "Global: Combine fields filter (exposed)" in Filter Criteria,and selected title & body filed to combine the search.Enabled, use autocomplete option. Works fine.
But, the serach performs only within the limit with 100chars. Beyond that, its not searching. So,if, the text which I searched is beyond 100chars, I will not get in the autocomplete result.
In the combine filter, there is an option: Unformatted dropdown , and if I enabled, in the auto-complete, I get full body content value. but, actually, I need it to be displayed with some limit.
Can somebody help me in getting the search with full article content in the body field in auto-complete results with some limit?
In simple:
Search: Full body content in article content type
Auto-complete results: If search text is present in the article body field, then display the result with 100chars limit. (If I display whole body content in auto-complete results, its not looking nice, so I can't use unformatted dropdown option)
